# How to lively save pandas dataframe to file?

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have a Python program that is controlling some machines and stores some data. The data is produced at a rate of about 20 rows per second (and about 10 columns or so). The whole run of this program can be as long as one week, as a result there is a large dataframe.

What are safe and correct ways to store this data? With safe I mean that if something fails in the day 6, I will still have all the data from days 1→6. With correct I mean not re-writing the whole dataframe to a file in each loop.

My current solution is a CSV file, I just print each row manually. This solution is both safe and correct, but the problem is that CSV does not preserve data types and also occupies more memory. So I would like to know if there is a binary solution. I like the feather format as it is really fast, but it does not allow to append rows.

Comment: What about not writing the data to a file, but storing it in a [database](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two easy options:

- store chunks of data (e.g. every 30 seconds or whatever suits your use case) into separate files; you can then postprocess them back into a single dataframe.
- store each row into an SQL database as it comes in. Sqlite will likely be a good start, but I'd maybe really go for PostgreSQL. That's what databases are meant for, after all.